# SQL Set SUM IN Update with inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having issues updating a column of my temp table in sql.
Here is my query.

```
UPDATE #temp
SET #temp.totalcredit = 
SUM(CASE WHEN c.ratetype = 'NRP' THEN d.Credit ELSE d.Credit * f.equivalent END)
from #temp a 
inner join theader b
on a.IV = b.docnum
and a.SOANUM is not null
inner join BillRun c
on rtrim(replace(
    case
        when charindex('-',b.comments,1) <> 6 AND charindex('-',b.comments,1) > 0
        then substring(ltrim(rtrim(b.comments)),1, charindex('-',b.comments,1)-1)
        when charindex(' ',b.comments,1) > 0
        then substring(ltrim(rtrim(b.comments)),1, charindex(' ',b.comments,1)-1)
        else left(ltrim( comments),10)
    end,'''','')) = c.BillRunCode OR c.BillRunCode = b.runcode
inner join BillRunProposalSummary d
on c.BillRunCode = d.BillRunCode and d.Credit > 0
inner join configforexrates f
on f.date = c.DocDate
```

Is there a way to get the sum and still update it this way?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server or Sybase?

Comment: using ms sql @jarlh

Comment: you have a table a to update and a temp table with alias a?

Comment: yep. the temp table has the alias A and it's the table i want to update @JoeTaras

Comment: No, you must have a table without alias in UPDATE. So you must have UPDATE #temp

Comment: It would still return the error "An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.", Also, I think you can use aliases on update statements with inner joins

Comment: @JoeTaras The join syntax is fine, as is the alias. The problem is only with the aggregation, which can't be done in an update. You have to use a subquery to perform the aggregation. Actually, the join itself is horrible, but the syntax seems to be fine. I'd suggest using another temp table to extract the data from theader that you want to join on, so you don't have to repeatedly call charindex in the join.

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: @ChrisFlynn id have to agree with the query being really bad, the table structure is pretty horrible so id have to resort to joins like this.

Comment: @AnilKumar i need to update a column of my temp table with the sum of another result set but updates like this do not allow aggregrates as values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
UPDATE A
SET A.TotalCredit = T.Credit
FROM #temp A
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT SUM(
    CASE C.RateType 
        WHEN 'NRP' THEN D.Credit 
    ELSE 
        D.Credit * F.Equivalent 
    END) AS Credit
FROM Theader B
inner join BillRun c
on rtrim(replace(
    case
        when charindex('-',b.comments,1) <> 6 AND charindex('-',b.comments,1) > 0
        then substring(ltrim(rtrim(b.comments)),1, charindex('-',b.comments,1)-1)
        when charindex(' ',b.comments,1) > 0
        then substring(ltrim(rtrim(b.comments)),1, charindex(' ',b.comments,1)-1)
        else left(ltrim( comments),10)
    end,'''','')) = c.BillRunCode OR c.BillRunCode = b.runcode
inner join BillRunProposalSummary d
on c.BillRunCode = d.BillRunCode and d.Credit > 0
inner join configforexrates f
on f.date = c.DocDate
WHERE B.DocNum = A.IV
) T
WHERE A.SOANUM IS NOT NULL
;
```

Comment: it works, i think. but im querying pretty large tables so it takes quite a long time to execute. I might have to rethink my approach to this. Thanks!